# JQuery how to fetch 2nd and 3rd TD content depend on 4th td click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here the html markup having a table, i need to fetch td's content on click and save it into hidden field.
**[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bpGXp/16/)**

**Html Markup :**

```
<table>
    <tr style="color:#333333;background-color:#F7F6F3;" class="odd">
        <td style="width:70px;" class="  sorting_1">1</td>
        <td class=" "> <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvworkcategory_ctl02_lblworkcategory">Customer Relations</span> 
        </td>
        <td>one</td>
        <td align="center" style="width:80px;" class=" ">
            <img atl="edit" style="border-width:0px;cursor:pointer" src="images/edt1.png" class="update_1" title="Edit" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvworkcategory_ctl02_Image1">
        </td>
        <td class=" "><a href="abc.aspx?id=1">View Details</a> 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="color:#333333;background-color:#F7F6F3;" class="odd">
        <td style="width:70px;" class="  sorting_1">2</td>
        <td class=" "> <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvworkcategory_ctl02_lblworkcategory">Marketing </span>

        </td>
        <td>two</td>
        <td align="center" style="width:80px;" class=" ">
            <img atl="edit" style="border-width:0px;cursor:pointer" src="images/edt1.png" class="update_2" title="Edit" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvworkcategory_ctl02_Image1">
        </td>
        <td class=" "><a href="abc.aspx?id=3">View Details</a>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="color:#333333;background-color:#F7F6F3;" class="odd">
        <td style="width:70px;" class="  sorting_1">3</td>
        <td class=" "> <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvworkcategory_ctl02_lblworkcategory">General</span>

        </td>
        <td>three</td>
        <td align="center" style="width:80px;" class=" ">
            <img atl="edit" style="border-width:0px;cursor:pointer" src="images/edt1.png" class="update_3" title="Edit" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvworkcategory_ctl02_Image1">
        </td>
        <td class=" "><a href="abc.aspx?id=3">View Details</a>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input id="hdid" type="hidden" />
<input id="hdcol2" type="hidden" />
<input id="hdcol3" type="hidden" />
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$("img[class^='update_']").live('click', function (event) {
    var getId = $(this).attr("class")
    $("#hdid").val(getId);
    alert(getId)
});
```

Comment: By "fetch td content" what does that mean?

Comment: what is the problem here for u.I think it is working

Comment: sorry.i saw that so i deleted my comment

Comment: @cgatian: mean i need to fetch column 2, column 3 values on click on `column 4` and have it into hidden field

Comment: 1. `.live()` is deprecated;
2. `align` attribute is deprecated;
3. inline styling is bad, use CSS + classes better.

Comment: 4. don't use jQuery 1.6.4

Comment: @moonwave99:  thanks for reply, but am using `old version Jquery lib`    which not support `.on()` so have to use `.live()` am used css its just for demo i did inline

Comment: Use more recent jQuery, and you can write CSS in fiddle as well : D

Comment: @moonwave99: Am at the ending phase of my project, and i dnt think its good to change the library at end, But forsure in new one i will use lastest Libs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(1).text();
```

and

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(2).text();
```

Demo `----->` http://jsfiddle.net/bpGXp/19/

Updated One `----->` http://jsfiddle.net/bpGXp/21/  (with no whitespace)

Comment: Thank you very much , earlier i was not aware with `.eq()`

Comment: its works, but with text there some extra white space how can i removed those extra white space()

Answer (score 1):

have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/bpGXp/18/

**CODE**

```
$("img[class^='update_']").live('click', function (event) {
    var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
    var tds = $(tr).find("td");
    alert($(tds[0]).text() + " | " + $(tds[1]).text() + " | " + $(tds[2]).text());

    //save col1, col2 and col3 values where you need it
});
```

hope it helps